# How to send buffer to a repl without showing it in prompt?

Tags: repl

I'm using [nodejs-repl](https://github.com/abicky/nodejs-repl.el), though the question applies to sending text to any repl.

I'd like to send a buffer to the repl, which I do with `C-c C-b`, but I don't want the buffer text to show in the prompt.

So instead of this:

```
> 0 + 1
1
> const seven = require('./seven);
const five = require('./five');
const add = require('./add');

const twelve = add(seven, five);
console.log(twelve);

12
>
```

I would instead something like see:

```
> 0 + 1
1
> loaded path/to/file.js
12
>
```

The `loaded path/to/file.js` isn't required, I basically just don't want to see all the buffer text.

I'm new to elisp and so all I can think to do is store the buffer text to a variable and somehow only show that variable (I don't know how to do this though).

Answer (score 1):

This example sends the command to the *shell* buffer, and displays the results but without displaying the command:

```
  (let* ((buf (get-buffer "*shell*"))
     (proc (get-buffer-process buf))
     (command "echo hello world\n"))
(comint-send-string proc command)
)
```

I *think* the same approach would work with any comint buffer.